# Java Spring Boot with mysql configuration doesn't start

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have been trying to start spring boot with mysql and haven't succeeded.
When i hit run the server just stopped after a few seconds just after the sql makes a query.

```
2017-11-05 04:13:04.607  WARN 4648 --- [           main] .t.AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2017-11-05 04:13:05.525  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-11-05 04:13:05.525  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.526  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.527  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.528  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.528  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2017-11-05 04:13:05.529  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
2017-11-05 04:13:05.531  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/auditevents || /auditevents.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AuditEventsMvcEndpoint.findByPrincipalAndAfterAndType(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
2017-11-05 04:13:05.532  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.532  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.534  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
2017-11-05 04:13:05.534  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2017-11-05 04:13:05.535  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.535  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.536  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.536  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-11-05 04:13:05.537  INFO 4648 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-11-05 04:13:05.946 DEBUG 4648 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        articulo0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        articulo0_.cantidad as cantidad2_0_0_,
        articulo0_.codigo as codigo3_0_0_,
        articulo0_.descripcion as descripc4_0_0_,
        articulo0_.nombre as nombre5_0_0_ 
    from
        articulo articulo0_ 
    where
        articulo0_.id=?
2017-11-05 04:13:05.991  INFO 4648 --- [           main] c.g.i.GestorInventarioApplicationTests   : Started GestorInventarioApplicationTests in 7.338 seconds (JVM running for 8.23)
2017-11-05 04:13:06.085  INFO 4648 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@4cc8eb05: startup date [Sun Nov 05 04:12:59 COT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-05 04:13:06.102  INFO 4648 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Here stops.

Entity:

```
package com.gestor.inventario;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="articulo")
public class Articulo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="codigo")
    private String codigo;
    @Column(name="descripcion")
    private String descripcion;
    @Column(name="cantidad")
    private int cantidad;

    public Articulo() {}

    public Articulo(long id, String nombre, String descripcion, String codigo, int cantidad) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setNombre(String vchNombre) {
        this.nombre = vchNombre;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad= cantidad;
    }

    public int getCantidad() {  
        return cantidad;
    }
}
```

seeder:

```
package com.gestor.inventario;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class dbSeeder implements CommandLineRunner {
    private ArticuloRepository articulosRepository;

    @Autowired
    public dbSeeder(ArticuloRepository articulosRepository) {
        this.articulosRepository = articulosRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        List<Articulo> articulos = new ArrayList<>();
        articulos.add(new Articulo(1, "Nombre1", "Descripcion1", "Codigo1", 100));
        articulosRepository.save(articulos);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.gestor.inventario;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/articulos")
public class Controller {
    private ArticuloRepository articuloRepository;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(ArticuloRepository articuloRepository) {
        this.articuloRepository = articuloRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Articulo> getAll() {
        return articuloRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<Articulo> insert(@RequestBody Articulo obj) {
        articuloRepository.save(obj);
        return articuloRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  List<Articulo> delete(@PathVariable long id){
        articuloRepository.delete(id);
        return articuloRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

repository:

```
package com.gestor.inventario;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ArticuloRepository extends JpaRepository<Articulo, Long>{

}
```

Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbinventory?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gyance</groupId>
    <artifactId>gestorInventario</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>gestorInventario</name>
    <description>Módulo de gestión de inventarios</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

database:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwK8x.png)

Comment: sure: CREATE TABLE articulo(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    codigo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT NOT NULL);

Comment: no it was just an error in my copy paste the database is like in the picture. I already tried changing all variable name, table name etc. 6 hours stuck with this problem x_X

Comment: @GustavoYance where is your main method? Can you include it?

Comment: It looks like it *is* starting, and then immediately shut down. As @YoshuaNahar said, we need your `main`. Most likely it's not annotated correctly (particularly, it may be in a different package from your components).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you try to run the boot program the compiler first will run the program using the application.java class check whether you had write the application.java class if you not include that first.

```
package package_name;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication//It's main spring annotations
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);//It should be include by default in every boot program
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `@SpringBootApplication` already contains `@EnableAutoConfiguration`
2) `@RestController` is absolutely useless in Spring main class

Answer (score 0):

To make your project run correctly you need to have something similair to this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class);
  }

}
```

The `@SpringBootApplication` contains the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which automatically starts **Tomcat** for you. Without this step, your application has no reason to stay active after your `void run(String... string)` method and exits!

At the very least you should include the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` instead of `@SpringBootApplication`, if you don't have bean configurations inside your `App` class.